# Java/Android Math Test: Got Curious About Int and Float Math/Conversion/Casting

Tags: java, android, math, floating-point, int

Was looking through a few different threads for some information on different types of math and conversions between int and float data types. Long story short I got sick of reading everyone's words with no tests to support anything. I therefore offer the opposite, here I wrote a little test for an android application that is actually running within an activity that has a constant animation active (more realistic in my opinion, at least for game devs). I wanted to get a somewhat of a grasp on this abstraction, and here's the code and LogCat results for my Droid running version 2.2.2:

**Results**:

```
NumberOfLoops = 100,000
LogCat:
06-28 00:17:40.439: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):    i=Math.Round(f): 83ms
06-28 00:17:40.439: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):           i=(int)f: 4ms
06-28 00:17:40.439: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):            f=6666f: 2ms
06-28 00:17:40.439: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):      f=(float)6666: 3ms
06-28 00:17:40.439: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):       int division: 5ms
06-28 00:17:40.439: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):     float division: 10ms
06-28 00:17:40.439: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417): int/float division: 14ms
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
06-28 00:18:03.017: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):    i=Math.Round(f): 102ms
06-28 00:18:03.017: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):           i=(int)f: 3ms
06-28 00:18:03.017: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):            f=6666f: 2ms
06-28 00:18:03.017: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):      f=(float)6666: 2ms
06-28 00:18:03.017: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):       int division: 5ms
06-28 00:18:03.017: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):     float division: 9ms
06-28 00:18:03.017: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417): int/float division: 13ms
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
06-28 00:18:04.915: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):    i=Math.Round(f): 97ms
06-28 00:18:04.915: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):           i=(int)f: 2ms
06-28 00:18:04.915: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):            f=6666f: 2ms
06-28 00:18:04.915: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):      f=(float)6666: 2ms
06-28 00:18:04.915: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):       int division: 5ms
06-28 00:18:04.915: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417):     float division: 9ms
06-28 00:18:04.923: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3417): int/float division: 13ms

NumberOfLoops = 1,000,0000
LogCat:
06-28 00:20:09.993: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):    i=Math.Round(f): 7569ms
06-28 00:20:09.993: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):           i=(int)f: 236ms
06-28 00:20:09.993: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):            f=6666f: 223ms
06-28 00:20:09.993: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):      f=(float)6666: 209ms
06-28 00:20:09.993: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):       int division: 474ms
06-28 00:20:09.993: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):     float division: 907ms
06-28 00:20:09.993: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454): int/float division: 1332ms
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
06-28 00:20:34.087: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):    i=Math.Round(f): 7533ms
06-28 00:20:34.087: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):           i=(int)f: 235ms
06-28 00:20:34.087: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):            f=6666f: 201ms
06-28 00:20:34.087: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):      f=(float)6666: 201ms
06-28 00:20:34.095: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):       int division: 470ms
06-28 00:20:34.095: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):     float division: 912ms
06-28 00:20:34.095: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454): int/float division: 1325ms
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
06-28 00:21:08.876: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):    i=Math.Round(f): 7527ms
06-28 00:21:08.876: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):           i=(int)f: 235ms
06-28 00:21:08.876: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):            f=6666f: 208ms
06-28 00:21:08.876: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):      f=(float)6666: 201ms
06-28 00:21:08.884: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):       int division: 469ms
06-28 00:21:08.884: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454):     float division: 905ms
06-28 00:21:08.884: DEBUG/MATH.TEST(3454): int/float division: 1333ms
```

Code:

```
long mathRoundTime = 0L;
long castingIntTime = 0L;

long usingFTime = 0L;
long castingFloatTime = 0L;

long integerMathTime = 0L;
long floatMathTime = 0L;
long mixedMathTime = 0L;

long mTimerDelta=0L; 
long mTimerFinish = 0L;

final int maxCycles=10000000;
int x=0; 
int iTest=0; 
int i1=6666; 
int i2=2;

float fTest=0f; 
float f1=6666f; 
float f2=2f;

// Test the int -Math.round- float
long mTimerStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (x=0;x<maxCycles;x++){
    iTest = Math.round(fTest);
}
mTimerFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
mTimerDelta = mTimerFinish - mTimerStart;
mathRoundTime = mTimerDelta;

// Test the int casting from Float
mTimerStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (x=0;x<maxCycles;x++){
    iTest = (int)(fTest);
}
mTimerFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
mTimerDelta = mTimerFinish - mTimerStart;
castingIntTime = mTimerDelta;

// casting from int with f
mTimerStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (x=0;x<maxCycles;x++){
    fTest = 6666f;
}
mTimerFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
mTimerDelta = mTimerFinish - mTimerStart;
usingFTime = mTimerDelta;

// casting from int with f
mTimerStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (x=0;x<maxCycles;x++){
    fTest = (float)6666;
}
mTimerFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
mTimerDelta = mTimerFinish - mTimerStart;
castingFloatTime = mTimerDelta;

// casting from int with f
mTimerStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (x=0;x<maxCycles;x++){
    iTest = i1/i2;
}
mTimerFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
mTimerDelta = mTimerFinish - mTimerStart;
integerMathTime = mTimerDelta;

// casting from int with f
mTimerStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (x=0;x<maxCycles;x++){
    fTest = f1/f2;
}
mTimerFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
mTimerDelta = mTimerFinish - mTimerStart;
floatMathTime = mTimerDelta;

// casting from int with f
mTimerStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (x=0;x<maxCycles;x++){
    fTest = i1/f2;
}
mTimerFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
mTimerDelta = mTimerFinish - mTimerStart;
mixedMathTime = mTimerDelta;


Log.d("MATH.TEST", "   i=Math.Round(f): " + Long.toString(mathRoundTime) + "ms");
Log.d("MATH.TEST", "          i=(int)f: " + Long.toString(castingIntTime)+ "ms");

Log.d("MATH.TEST", "           f=6666f: " + Long.toString(usingFTime)+ "ms");
Log.d("MATH.TEST", "     f=(float)6666: " + Long.toString(castingFloatTime)+ "ms");

Log.d("MATH.TEST", "      int division: " + Long.toString(integerMathTime)+ "ms");
Log.d("MATH.TEST", "    float division: " + Long.toString(floatMathTime)+ "ms");
Log.d("MATH.TEST", "int/float division: " + Long.toString(mixedMathTime)+ "ms");
```

Would love to hear some discussion as to why some of this is as it is.. and if something seems wrong just let me know and I can re-run and post. Otherwise go ahead and do it yourself, I just wanted to share my findings most of all.

Comment: I would suggest you use `System.nanoTime()` for performance timing. It's supposed to return the most precise value.

Comment: Should this be a community wiki?

Comment: No clue, if so let me know. As @Mikola said this might have been due to JVM.

Comment: +1 on making it a wiki. There's no question here.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit funny to me.  The timings for your simple examples like:

```
for (x=0;x<maxCycles;x++){
    iTest = (int)(fTest);
}
```

Are waaaay too low.  I strongly suspect they are either getting inlined or else having the conversion moved outside the loop body.  Can you try running it in a situation where fTest varies with i as you loop?  Otherwise you aren't going to get accurate measurements if the JVM can pull a fast one.

Comment: will absolutely try that tomorrow and post back with those results. I however didn't care what was actually going on in the beginning, I just wanted some simple benchmarks for tasks like these.

Comment: they're really too long for iterating 100,000 and 1,000,000,000 times? Like I said this is all being done while there is a constant animation and buttons in a view. I tried to do something that wasn't just the phone sitting there doing math for the purpose of doing math.

Comment: @While-E:  Right.  What I think might be happening is that it moved the type conversion outside the loop and the only that is getting measured is the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

These surely are some very interesting findings. But I suspect if the JVM has optimized the loops. It would be interesting to see if the code got expanded. (Loop expansion was once a optimization technique when C was still popular and every CPU clock counts)

e.g

```
final int cycles = maxCycles / 100
for (x=0;x<cycles;x++){
    fTest = 6666f;
    fTest = 6666f;
... 100 times ...
    fTest = 6666f;
    fTest = 6666f;
}
```

Or, if possible, make them even 1000 times... and even one step further: write a program to generate the source code which makes every line has a unique number to rule out any possible optimization by the JVM.